# Where should I store (and manage) the data related to UI/icons?

Tags: angularjs, web-applications

I don't known if it's the right place to ask this since it's more about best practices than bug fixing. Please tell me if I'm wrong I'll remove the question.

I'm working on a web application (with AngularJS, but I'm also looking for generic answer).
I have a list of 5-15 "things" with some data related to them. Let's say these things are called "Profile Card" with information such as *Name*, *Quantity*, *Description*, etc.

All this data is stored in database. Then they're mapped in some objects/entities, then attached to a model and displayed in the view.

Each Profile Card has a specific icon. In my project, these icons are managed by the font-awesome library and defined by something like **fa-user**, **fa-bank**, **fa-beer**, etc.

My question is: where should I store and manage this icon information ?

Since it's UI related only I don't know if it should be stored in the database or even in the business layers.

I'm working with AngularJS, should I managed them in the controller by something like:

**HTML**

```
<i ng-class="getClassIcon(foo.profile)"></i>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.getClassIcon= function (profile) {
    switch(profile) {
    case 'user':
        return 'fa-user';
    case 'bank':
        return 'fa-bank';

    /**
     *   Other cases
    **/

    default:
        return 'fa-folder';
    }
}
```